# Getting wrong mismatch result in two strings in C

Tags: c

I am trying to find the percentage of mismatch between two strings in C but I am getting wrong answer. I have no idea why the program is showing wrong answer.

Please help me to get the answer.

My code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[1000], s2[1000];
    printf("S1: ");
    gets(s1);
    printf("S2: ");
    gets(s2);
    int match = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(s2); j++)
        {
            if (s1[i] == s2[j])
            {
                match++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Mismatch: %d%%\n", ((strlen(s1) - match) / strlen(s1)) * 100);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
S1: Debu
S2: Zebu
```

Getting output:

```
Mismatch: 0%
```

Expected output:

```
Mismatch: 25%
```

Please help me to get the expected answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only uses integers. No integer times 100 is 25. So there is no way that multiplying an integer by 100 can ever yield 25. So expecting 25 as output is unreasonable.

Maybe you meant `(100 * (strlen(s1) - match)) / strlen(s1)`?

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Exactly I wanted that.